# How to remove \n from JSON string object using JAVA

Tags: java, json

I am working on twitter data where it has lot of special characters which I am able to decode them. But when coming to new line i.e., \n, facing below error.

```
Exception in thread "Twitter_StreamThread-1" org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at 4911 [character 4912 line 1]
```

Tried to resolve by using REGEX,replaceAll,pattern matcher but nothing has wroked.

**Sample JSON object where it is failing to parse.**

```
{"[0].created_at":"Sat May 01 06:11:21  0000 2021","[0].id":1388375470341644292,"[0].id_str":"1388375470341644292","[0].full_text":"RT @amirs6500: Sharjeel Usmani is being targeted by sanghis 4 calling a spade a spade. People indulged in Riots, genocides, rapes, mass mur…","[0].truncated":false,"[0].display_text_range[0]":0,"[0].display_text_range[1]":140,"[0].entities.hashtags":[],"[0].entities.symbols":[],"[0].entities.user_mentions[0].screen_name":"amirs6500","[0].entities.user_mentions[0].name":"NADEEM SHAIKH","[0].entities.user_mentions[0].id":745956780119834624,"[0].entities.user_mentions[0].id_str":"745956780119834624","[0].entities.user_mentions[0].indices[0]":3,"[0].entities.user_mentions[0].indices[1]":13,"[0].entities.urls":[],"[0].metadata.iso_language_code":"en","[0].metadata.result_type":"recent","[0].source":" a href \"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel \"nofollow\" Twitter for Android \/a ","[0].in_reply_to_status_id":null,"[0].in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"[0].in_reply_to_user_id":null,"[0].in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"[0].in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"[0].user.id":1373724258640097280,"[0].user.id_str":"1373724258640097280","[0].user.name":"Arbaz Khan","[0].user.screen_name":"Akhan6474","[0].user.location":"Mira Road, Mumbai","[0].user.description":"","[0].user.url":null,"[0].user.entities.description.urls":[],"[0].user.protected":false,"[0].user.followers_count":0,"[0].user.friends_count":12,"[0].user.listed_count":0,"[0].user.created_at":"Sun Mar 21 19:52:50  0000 2021","[0].user.favourites_count":4,"[0].user.utc_offset":null,"[0].user.time_zone":null,"[0].user.geo_enabled":false,"[0].user.verified":false,"[0].user.statuses_count":10,"[0].user.lang":null,"[0].user.contributors_enabled":false,"[0].user.is_translator":false,"[0].user.is_translation_enabled":false,"[0].user.profile_background_color":"F5F8FA","[0].user.profile_background_image_url":null,"[0].user.profile_background_image_url_https":null,"[0].user.profile_background_tile":false,"[0].user.profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1373724420523487232\/Dbf76rdD_normal.jpg","[0].user.profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1373724420523487232\/Dbf76rdD_normal.jpg","[0].user.profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","[0].user.profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","[0].user.profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","[0].user.profile_text_color":"333333","[0].user.profile_use_background_image":true,"[0].user.has_extended_profile":true,"[0].user.default_profile":true,"[0].user.default_profile_image":false,"[0].user.following":false,"[0].user.follow_request_sent":false,"[0].user.notifications":false,"[0].user.translator_type":"none","[0].user.withheld_in_countries":[],"[0].geo":null,"[0].coordinates":null,"[0].place":null,"[0].contributors":null,"[0].retweeted_status.created_at":"Sat May 01 05:46:56  0000 2021","[0].retweeted_status.id":1388369324117692420,"[0].retweeted_status.id_str":"1388369324117692420","[0].retweeted_status.full_text":"Sharjeel Usmani is being targeted by sanghis 4 calling a spade a spade. People indulged in Riots, genocides, rapes, mass murdering across the nation, doesn’t have any morality in teaching lessons of humanity for activist like @SharjeelUsmani #StandWithSharjeelUsmani","[0].retweeted_status.truncated":false,"[0].retweeted_status.display_text_range[0]":0,"[0].retweeted_status.display_text_range[1]":266,"[0].retweeted_status.entities.hashtags[0].text":"StandWithSharjeelUsmani","[0].retweeted_status.entities.hashtags[0].indices[0]":242,"[0].retweeted_status.entities.hashtags[0].indices[1]":266,"[0].retweeted_status.entities.symbols":[],"[0].retweeted_status.entities.user_mentions[0].screen_name":"SharjeelUsmani","[0].retweeted_status.entities.user_mentions[0].name":"Sharjeel Usmani","[0].retweeted_status.entities.user_mentions[0].id":1049960593,"[0].retweeted_status.entities.user_mentions[0].id_str":"1049960593","[0].retweeted_status.entities.user_mentions[0].indices[0]":226,"[0].retweeted_status.entities.user_mentions[0].indices[1]":241,"[0].retweeted_status.entities.urls":[],"[0].retweeted_status.metadata.iso_language_code":"en","[0].retweeted_status.metadata.result_type":"recent","[0].retweeted_status.source":" a href \"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel \"nofollow\" Twitter for Android \/a ","[0].retweeted_status.in_reply_to_status_id":null,"[0].retweeted_status.in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"[0].retweeted_status.in_reply_to_user_id":null,"[0].retweeted_status.in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"[0].retweeted_status.in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"[0].retweeted_status.user.id":745956780119834624,"[0].retweeted_status.user.id_str":"745956780119834624","[0].retweeted_status.user.name":"NADEEM SHAIKH","[0].retweeted_status.user.screen_name":"amirs6500","[0].retweeted_status.user.location":"Navi Mumbai, India","[0].retweeted_status.user.description":"NADEEM SHAIKH\n Dj\n4th may\ntarus","[0].retweeted_status.user.url":null,"[0].retweeted_status.user.entities.description.urls":[],"[0].retweeted_status.user.protected":false,"[0].retweeted_status.user.followers_count":63,"[0].retweeted_status.user.friends_count":140,"[0].retweeted_status.user.listed_count":0,"[0].retweeted_status.user.created_at":"Thu Jun 23 12:28:50  0000 2016","[0].retweeted_status.user.favourites_count":880,"[0].retweeted_status.user.utc_offset":null,"[0].retweeted_status.user.time_zone":null,"[0].retweeted_status.user.geo_enabled":true,"[0].retweeted_status.user.verified":false,"[0].retweeted_status.user.statuses_count":271,"[0].retweeted_status.user.lang":null,"[0].retweeted_status.user.contributors_enabled":false,"[0].retweeted_status.user.is_translator":false,"[0].retweeted_status.user.is_translation_enabled":false,"[0].retweeted_status.user.profile_background_color":"F5F8FA","[0].retweeted_status.user.profile_background_image_url":null,"[0].retweeted_status.user.profile_background_image_url_https":null,"[0].retweeted_status.user.profile_background_tile":false,"[0].retweeted_status.user.profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/745962980748099586\/zK6--YPG_normal.jpg","[0].retweeted_status.user.profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/745962980748099586\/zK6--YPG_normal.jpg","[0].retweeted_status.user.profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/745956780119834624\/1466686403","[0].retweeted_status.user.profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","[0].retweeted_status.user.profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","[0].retweeted_status.user.profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","[0].retweeted_status.user.profile_text_color":"333333","[0].retweeted_status.user.profile_use_background_image":true,"[0].retweeted_status.user.has_extended_profile":true,"[0].retweeted_status.user.default_profile":true,"[0].retweeted_status.user.default_profile_image":false,"[0].retweeted_status.user.following":false,"[0].retweeted_status.user.follow_request_sent":false,"[0].retweeted_status.user.notifications":false,"[0].retweeted_status.user.translator_type":"none","[0].retweeted_status.user.withheld_in_countries":[],"[0].retweeted_status.geo":null,"[0].retweeted_status.coordinates":null,"[0].retweeted_status.place":null,"[0].retweeted_status.contributors":null,"[0].retweeted_status.is_quote_status":false,"[0].retweeted_status.retweet_count":1,"[0].retweeted_status.favorite_count":1,"[0].retweeted_status.favorited":false,"[0].retweeted_status.retweeted":false,"[0].retweeted_status.lang":"en","[0].is_quote_status":false,"[0].retweet_count":1,"[0].favorite_count":0,"[0].favorited":false,"[0].retweeted":false,"[0].lang":"en","[0].risk_events_keyword_id":34,"[0].keyword_id":7,"[0].risk_events_catergory":"Civil%20Unrest","[0].keywords":"Riots"}
```

Entire object will be taken as string and tried to parse below way as well in java class but resulted in same error.

`String jsonStr = JsonFlattener.flatten(result).replaceAll("\n", "\\n");`

Where I am going wrong to parse this "\n". I refered several posts and blogs where they stated to replace \n with \n. But why is this not working in this kind of JSON object. What am I missing. It would be very helpful if this was resolved.

Comment: Is it possible to use `jsonStr = jsonStr.replace("\n", "\\n");`?

Comment: I have also tried that, even that was not working. @Aadi

Comment: Is there any other possible way ?? I tried in eclipse but eclipse was automatically inserting \ before double quote of every key and value  so working there. But I should execute this code in command prompt where replace function was not working.

Any response was much appreciated.

Comment: The issue was resolved. Actually error was occuring at \u0000 from main array object. So i have cleared that by replaceAll("\\\\u0000","");